# ElasticSearch script filter compare two field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use script filter to get all match that the score value equals to maxScore value. but it is not work.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc['match.score'].value == doc['match.maxScore'].value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this error :

```
{
    "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[yk_PnKg9SOaf1d8acCsjvw][cobink_search][0]: SearchParseException[[cobink_search][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"script":{"script":"doc['match.score'].value == doc['match.maxScore'].value"}}}}}]]]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }{[0jYKWZlyQiiVPHlzmoMjkA][cobink_search][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Hammer Harrison][inet[/192.168.1.100:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[cobink_search][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"script":{"script":"doc['match.score'].value == doc['match.maxScore'].value"}}}}}]]]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }{[yk_PnKg9SOaf1d8acCsjvw][cobink_search][2]: SearchParseException[[cobink_search][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"script":{"script":"doc['match.score'].value == doc['match.maxScore'].value"}}}}}]]]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }{[yk_PnKg9SOaf1d8acCsjvw][cobink_search][3]: SearchParseException[[cobink_search][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"script":{"script":"doc['match.score'].value == doc['match.maxScore'].value"}}}}}]]]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }{[0jYKWZlyQiiVPHlzmoMjkA][cobink_search][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Hammer Harrison][inet[/192.168.1.100:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[cobink_search][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"script":{"script":"doc['match.score'].value == doc['match.maxScore'].value"}}}}}]]]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }]",
    "status": 400
}
```

Thanks you guys :)

Comment: Please read logs which says scripting is disabled. You need to enable it from elasticsearch.yml

Comment: And also set the scripting language to groovy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic scripting is disabled in your case. Add the following line in your `elasticsearch.yml` file to enable dynamic scripting. Then your query should work. But beware this can leave a security hole in your Elasticsearch cluster. Read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/scripting-security) and [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/modules-scripting.html).

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Comment: Thanks you :) it's work. 
Yes it's not good for securty, so can we do either ?

Comment: It is a security concern only when your Elasticsearch cluster is exposed. If not, it should be fine. Please mark this as answer if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.x and above you need to use

```
script.indexed: on
script.inline: on
```

in your elasticsearch.yml file, to enable the scripts.